# Talend : migrate data maintaining the same row sequence in input db and output db

Tags: oracle, migration, sybase, talend

I am migrating data from sybase to oracle using talend. I am using tSybaseInput for input and tOracleOutput for output db. I am mapping them through t_Map in some whereas direct in others.

After running the job, the row order is not maintained i.e. the order in which the data comes from sybase is not same as reflected in oracle. I need the order to be same so that I can validate the data later by outputting the data of both db to csv's and then comparing them(right now I am sorting them(unix sort) ..but it seems wrong).

Please suggest a way to maintain row order of input db in output db.

Also , is my method of validation correct or should I try something else?

Comment: Hi, Don't forget to upvote and/or accept helpful answers.  :?)

Answer (score 0):

The character sets and sort orders between the two vendors may be slightly different, which probably why you are seeing a change in the order.  You may want to add a numeric key value to your tables in the Sybase DB, which can then be used to force a particular order once the data is imported into Oracle.

As for validation, if you are already using Unix command line, once you have a key value, you should just be able to use `diff` to compare the two CSV files without having to involve Excel.  Alternatively you can add both Sybase and Oracle as data sources for Excel, and query the data directly into your worksheets, instead of generating CSV.